# Since OTA update to Marshmallow my gyroscope based app does not work anymore

Tags: android, sensors, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've upgraded my Nexus 5 to Marshmallow with OTA. 
Since the update simple sensor based activity does not work anymore. 
The following code do what it should to do on others devices (Galaxy S4 Lolipop, AVD, ...)

Does someone has experiment this too ? Do I miss something ?

Here is the code:

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.rouk1.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="fr.rouk1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package fr.rouk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView mText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        initSensor();
    }

    private void initSensor() {

        SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if (sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) == null) {
            sm.registerListener(this,
                    sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            sm.registerListener(this,
                    sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            sm.registerListener(this,
                    sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        } else {
            sm.registerListener(this,
                    sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // this is never called

        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < event.values.length; i++) {
            s = s.concat(String.format("%.4f, ", event.values[i]));
        }

        mText.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        switch (accuracy) {

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH:
                Log.d("rouk1", "SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH");
                break;

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW:
                Log.d("rouk1", "SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW");
                break;

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM:
                Log.d("rouk1", "SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM");
                break;

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT:
                Log.d("rouk1", "SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT");
                break;

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE:
                Log.d("rouk1", "SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When an app crash, you can check logcat for crash reason. probebly it will give you hint on why it crashed. sharing the logcat can help understand the problem. looking at a crashing code isn't that useful without having knowing why it crashed.

Comment: The app does not crash, the function `onSensorChanged` is just never called.

Comment: how do you know `onSensorChanged` is not called.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708 related?

Comment: Because it is supposed to change the value of a TextView. Moreover putting a breakpoint in it is a pretty obvious solution to see if it is called. I have this issue in foreground mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189681&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).
Temporary solution is to use `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` instead of `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`.